# UINavigationController - rotation issues iOS6

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, orientation

I've subclassed the UINavigationController as follows:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

However I've come unstuck on pushing a view controller in an initial orientation differing to its' parent. In my case the parent view is portrait only:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

But I wish the pushed view to be landscape only - it'll only behave as such after manually changing the orientation of the device.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I'd much appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction. (I've only got a hacky solution so far...)

---

EDIT:

Following shows how I'm initiating the subclassed UINavigationController

```
PortraitView *vc = [[PortraitView alloc] init];
    SubClassedNav *navController = [[SubClassedNav alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And how I subsequently push a new view:

```
LandscapeView *vc = [[LandscapeView alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have this exact same setup in one of my apps and it works as you suggest. Are you sure it's setup as you describe? My only thought is what orientations have you set to support in your Info.plist?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The info.plist supports all orientations so unfortunately my error doesn't seem to lie there. If you have it running fine though, I suspect I'm making an elementary mistake somewhere..

Comment: Have you double-checked you're actually using your sub-classed nav controller?

Comment: Edited to show how I've gone about it. I'd be grateful if you find a glaring mistake!

Comment: InsertWittyName, as I've still not progressed on this, would it be possible for you to point me to a project that correctly implements this feature, or post your implementation here?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you setup `[window setRootViewController:controller]` in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Checked but no joy :(
Could you possibly post/point me to a functioning project?